# Remove Title bar from splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio

How can remove title bar from splash screen?

I have two  activity ( Main Activity and splash screen avtivity ) . I uesd the code `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` for the two activity to hide the title bar. so, it is removed from  main activity but not removed from splash screen activity.

Screenshot for splash screen:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17dC-REuko1zoQztUlUVcZQBkO4mEjhsK/view?usp=sharing

Screenshot for main activity:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GmY72IRl8_--PGfo2qr7abrcZj4zxbj/view?usp=sharing

The code is the following :

MainActivity.Jave:

```
package com.example.acer;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //remove App Title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://alkhaleej-med.com/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }




}
```

SplashScreen.jave:

```
package com.example.acer;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //remove App Title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(4000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_splash_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.acer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go To res-values-styles and change your base theme to NoActionBar 
e.g.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are half way there:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```